# activate actionlistener of jradiobutton after a jbutton is click

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, jradiobutton

so i have jradiobuttons and their listeners contains like this:

```
if(VotePresidentPanel.rbPres1.isSelected()){
                int[] incrementVote={1};
                for (int v : incrementVote){
                    resultP1 = (pvotes[v - 1]+=1);
                }
                ResultPresidentPanel.lblResPres1.setText(Integer.toString(resultP1));
            }
```

but i want the listeners of my jradiobuttons to only function AFTER i clicked a certain jbutton. i tried putting the listeners of jradiobutton inside the listener of jbutton but it still doesn't work. here's the code of what i mentioned that i tried doing:

```
if(e.getSource().equals(VoteButtonsPanel.btnVote)){
            if(VotePresidentPanel.rbPres1.isSelected()){
                int[] incrementVote={1};
                for (int v : incrementVote){
                    resultP1 = (pvotes[v - 1]+=1);
                }
                ResultPresidentPanel.lblResPres1.setText(Integer.toString(resultP1));
            }
            //...and other listeners for the other jradiobuttons
}
```

please help thank you so much :)

---

i have these jradiobuttons

```
() Pres1
() Pres2
() Pres3
() Pres4
```

i want them to be still clickable as it is a voting system, but my problem is every time i click on the radio buttons, the votes will increment even tho i still haven't clicked the `VOTE` button. i want the votes to increment only if after i clicked the `VOTE` button.

the listeners of jradiobuttons are like this/the functions of increment:

```
if(VotePresidentPanel.rbPres1.isSelected()){
                    int[] incrementVote={1};
                    for (int v : incrementVote){
                        resultP1 = (pvotes[v - 1]+=1);
                    }
                    ResultPresidentPanel.lblResPres1.setText(Integer.toString(resultP1));
                }
```

and i tried putting them inside the block of my `VOTE` listener, but still doesn't work. thank you for any help :)

**EDIT 2 this is what i tried base from the reply of copeg**

```
        boolean enableJRadioButton = false;
        if(e.getSource().equals(VoteButtonsPanel.btnVote)){
            enableJRadioButton=true;
        }
        if(VotePresidentPanel.rbPres1.isSelected()){
            if(enableJRadioButton==true){
                int[] incrementVote={1};
                for (int v : incrementVote){
                    resultP1 = (pvotes[v - 1]+=1);
                }
                ResultPresidentPanel.lblResPres1.setText(Integer.toString(resultP1));
            }
        }
```

Comment: `i want the listeners of my jradiobuttons to only function AFTER i clicked a certain jbutto`  Disable the JRadioButton's, and enable when the `JButton` is clicked. `but it doesn't work` It helps to fully explain what you mean by `doesn't work`, and also helps to post an [mcve]

Comment: @copeg i edited my question i hope it's understandable now hehehe. but yes i will try your suggestion and i'll let you know if it work thank you so much :)

Comment: @copeg oh it didn't worked. can you tell me how to do it? i did `setEnabled(false)` the radiobuttons on where i declared them and then `setEnabled(true)` them inside the block of `if(e.getSource().equals(VoteButtonsPanel.btnVote)){}` but i can't click them anymore. i'll edit my question for further clarifications hehehe :)

Comment: `but i can't click them anymore` That's the point of disabling. Having them clickable was not part of your posted requirements

Comment: @copeg i already edited my question. hehehe sorry for not including it hehehe

Comment: Your edit makes it sound like you only want to take action when vote is clicked, which makes me wonder why you need an ActionListener on the `JRadioButton`. Just tally the vote when the JButton is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but i want the listeners of my jradiobuttons to only function AFTER i clicked a certain jbutton.

If you wish to have the JRadioButton still enabled, but not have it's ActionListener fire you can use a boolean flag that is evaluated in the `JRadioButton` ActionListener, initialize it to `false` and set to `true` in the `JButton` ActionListener

```
boolean enableJRadioButton = false;
...
final JRadioButton myRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Do Something");
myRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if ( enableJRadioButton ){
            //do something
        }
    }
});

myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        enableJRadioButton = true;
        //do something else if necessary
    }
});
```

If you don't mind if the JRadioButton is enabled, consider enabling/disabling the `JRadioButton`s only after the `JButton` is clicked - eg in an `ActionListener` added to the `JButton`.

Comment: i think i did it wrong :/ or i just understand it wrong but it doesn't work. here's what i tried `boolean enableJRadioButton = false;` then for the JButton `if(e.getSource().equals(VoteButtonsPanel.btnVote)){
   enableJRadioButton=true; }` and for my JRadioButton `if(VotePresidentPanel.rbPres1.isSelected()){
   if(enableJRadioButton==true){
    int[] incrementVote={1};
    for (int v : incrementVote){
     resultP1 = (pvotes[v - 1]+=1);
    }
    ResultPresidentPanel.lblResPres1.setText(Integer.toString(resultP1));
   }
  }`

Comment: Make an edit to you original question - code posted in comments formats horribly.

Comment: The boolean is in the wrong scope (eg local to the method)...it must be moved outside the `actionPerformed` method. A debugger (or simply just some println's( would be quite valuable to you here